# Problem with asset browser importing objects with drivers attached that reference scenes

Tags: drivers, asset-browser

When I import an object from the asset browser that has any drivers on it that use "Single Property" and have the ID Block set to "Scene" the object instead gets placed in a newly created scene different from the one I was trying to import it into.

It also doesn't matter of the scene names are the same. For example if I import the object into a project with one scene just called "Scene", which is the name of the scene the ID block was set to use as well, it will instead create a new scene called "Scene.001" and place the object in that. Trying to link any objects over to the required scene just removes the scene settings from the drivers, so I have to go back in and redo each and every driver.

Also I noticed that when I click over to the newly made scene upon import, such as Scene.001 from my example, I noticed that it brings in everything from that project file that the asset was saved in, non marked assets and all.

Does anyone know of a viable fix for this problem?

Comment: Hello, I think unfortunately right now this is a limitation of the system, to avoid non functional assets, every single object that is tied to it will also be imported alongside with it.

Comment: That's a shame, I hope it gets fixed in the future at least. Thank you for the answer though.